# xbox 360 IE browser testing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, internet-explorer, emulation, xbox360

potentially obscure, but we've just had a dev request come through to specifically support Internet Explorer on the Xbox 360 (not One) browser.

I've raised a feature request with BrowserStack but they don't currently support it have and neither does Parallel - amongst the other usual sources. In addition searches online and within the xbox 360 developer docs have yealded no results for any available emulator for this platform (and damnit but the boss won't let us put an xbox on expenses ;) )

Has anyone come across an emulator or way of testing this scenario on their dev travels?

FYI we're testing a JS, Angular SPA ideally from OSX but could utilise Windows if a solution was available on that platform - paid for options are completely acceptable.

all help and advise and off the wall suggestions welcome at this stage!

Comment: Ultimately there is no substitute for a real device for testing that sort of thing - especially when you want to test things like "Are the UI elements big enough to use with the controller?". You can pick up a used xbox from amazon for £50 which isn't a big dent in an expenses budget. If you really can't convince your boss to invest, then maybe your client will supply you with a machine.

Comment: yeah, I'm working on that @Quentin, but it just doesn't seem likely either will go for it. Client found research saying people do Christmas shopping through the XBox console... TBH I'm not expecting there to be a solution to this, I'm just living in hope.

Comment: Are you still looking for advice on this?

Comment: hi Neil, we don't have an immediate requirement for this anymore but certainly it's going to come up again so if you have any insight regarding emulators etc that'd always be appreciated.