# is there a simulator for games console browsers?

Tags: javascript, browser, single-page-application, simulator

I need to test an SPA on various devices which include browsers for Playstation 3/4 and Xbox 360/one. I'm struggling to find any options for this other than buying consoles (not viable).

Any suggestions? I've tried usual suspects like BrowserStack etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably not waht you wanted to hear but I had this same issue last year for the xBox consoles and there was nothing available - the only advice was to purchase actual consoles, luckily we eventually borrowed one, but I was in contact with BS directly and there were no plans to introduce this.

the thread (incase useful): [xbox 360 IE browser testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33869915/xbox-360-ie-browser-testing)

Though new things come out all the time and maybe you'll be luckier

Comment: oh that's a shame but glad to know before wasting too much time! thanks